# Convert date to string in custom format

Tags: sql

I need to `SELECT` a date field but export it as `STRING`. Not date formatted in a specific way but pure `STRING`. For example if I have a date 06-May-2016, I need it to be exported as "06.2016". I tried something like:

```
SELECT convert ( "Application_Date", 'MM.YYYY')
```

but that's just rubbish. It seems like a simple issue, but I've been searching for an answer for some time now and found nothing.

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (convert is a product specific function.)

Comment: May is fifth month right? so expected output should be '05.2016'

Comment: yeah.. sorry about that ... it should be 05.206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I just needed to change:
SELECT FORMAT("Application_Date",'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Application_Date
to
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT("Application_Date",'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Application_Date

Answer (score 0):

try this,it is for MS SQL.

```
1. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) AS [YYYY.MM.DD]
2. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
3. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111), '/', '-') AS [YYYY-MM-DD]

or

SELECT convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 121)  – yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
```

Comment: Can you please let us know which dbms this is for? (Lots of product specific functions there.)

Comment: dashDB ... sorry, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

You can use format instead of convert as follows:

```
SELECT FORMAT("Application_Date",'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Application_Date
```

instead of 'YYYY-MM-DD' use a format which you want to. Hope it will help u.

Comment: Can you please let us know which dbms this is for? (Product specific SQL there.)

Comment: I am using dashDB and I kepp getting this error:
   No authorized routine named "FORMAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.69.56  
  
and this is exactly what I am entering:  
SELECT format ("Application_Date", 'MM.YYYY') as "newdate"  from CANDIDATE_ACTIVITIES;

Comment: Just remove the double quotes of Application_Date and check it. Not sure actually.